# gtk3 and gtk4 in Msys2 giving error with golang

Tags: go, gtk, gtk3, msys2, cgo

I am trying to use gotk3 package with golang using instructions from [here](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3) and [here](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/#using-gtk-from-msys2-packages) on Msys2 on Windows. I am trying to compile following code:

```
// from: https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3
package main

import (
    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize GTK without parsing any command line arguments.
    gtk.Init(nil)

    // Create a new toplevel window, set its title, and connect it to the
    // "destroy" signal to exit the GTK main loop when it is destroyed.
    win, err := gtk.WindowNew(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to create window:", err)
    }
    win.SetTitle("Simple Example")
    win.Connect("destroy", func() {
        gtk.MainQuit()
    })

    // Create a new label widget to show in the window.
    l, err := gtk.LabelNew("Hello, gotk3!")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to create label:", err)
    }

    // Add the label to the window.
    win.Add(l)

    // Set the default window size.
    win.SetDefaultSize(800, 600)

    // Recursively show all widgets contained in this window.
    win.ShowAll()

    // Begin executing the GTK main loop.  This blocks until
    // gtk.MainQuit() is run.
    gtk.Main()
}
```

I tried command "go build mysrc.go" after installing gtk3 (using command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3`) but I get following error:

```
$ go build mysrc.go
# github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib
cgo-gcc-prolog: In function '_cgo_200740c87a77_Cfunc_g_binding_get_source':
cgo-gcc-prolog:71:2: warning: 'g_binding_get_source' is deprecated: Use 'g_binding_dup_source' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
In file included from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:24,
                 from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:30,
                 from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:30,
                 from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:28,
                 from I:\Go_amd64_pkgs\pkg\mod\github.com\gotk3\gotk3@v0.6.1\glib\gbinding.go:3:
I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:115:23: note: declared here
  115 | GObject *             g_binding_get_source          (GBinding *binding);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cgo-gcc-prolog: In function '_cgo_200740c87a77_Cfunc_g_binding_get_target':
cgo-gcc-prolog:107:2: warning: 'g_binding_get_target' is deprecated: Use 'g_binding_dup_target' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:119:23: note: declared here
  119 | GObject *             g_binding_get_target          (GBinding *binding);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
go build github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gdk: invalid flag in pkg-config --libs: -Wl,-luuid
```

I also tried after installing gtk4 (using command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk4`) in Msys2. However, following is the error:

```
$ go build mysrc.go
# github.com/gotk3/gotk3/glib
cgo-gcc-prolog: In function '_cgo_200740c87a77_Cfunc_g_binding_get_source':
cgo-gcc-prolog:71:2: warning: 'g_binding_get_source' is deprecated: Use 'g_binding_dup_source' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
In file included from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:24,
                 from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:30,
                 from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:30,
                 from I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:28,
                 from I:\Go_amd64_pkgs\pkg\mod\github.com\gotk3\gotk3@v0.6.1\glib\gbinding.go:3:
I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:115:23: note: declared here
  115 | GObject *             g_binding_get_source          (GBinding *binding);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cgo-gcc-prolog: In function '_cgo_200740c87a77_Cfunc_g_binding_get_target':
cgo-gcc-prolog:107:2: warning: 'g_binding_get_target' is deprecated: Use 'g_binding_dup_target' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
I:/msys2/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:119:23: note: declared here
  119 | GObject *             g_binding_get_target          (GBinding *binding);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
go build github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gdk: invalid flag in pkg-config --libs: -Wl,-luuid
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: This <https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/issues/373>?

Comment: Basically I mean Mattn's [suggestion](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/issues/373#issuecomment-474263201) to [whitelist flags](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InvalidFlag#what-can-i-do) via `CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW`.

Comment: I don't know anything about Go, but you might be able to edit the `/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/???.pc` file of this library (of GTK, I think?) to replace `-Wl,-luuid` with just `-luuid`, it should do the same thing. But if whitelisting a flag works, it's probably a better idea.